# How to encode/decode a URL string in TMS WEB Core using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, urlencode, urldecode, tms, tms-web-core

In my FireMonkey Apps, I can simply add the `System.NetEncoding` unit to my uses list and then use the `TNetEncoding.URL.Encode()` and `TNetEncoding.URL.Decode()` functions, but the `System.NetEncoding` isn't available in TMS WEB Core.

I've also tried the `IdURI` and `HTTPApp` units, but they're not available either.

Is there perhaps a TMS unit for encoding and decoding URLs in TMS WEB Core?

Comment: If this is about JS again then it knows [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) already.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi has a long history full of timult dealing with Url encoding:

- **TIdURI.URLEncode(url)** - [buggy](https://marc.durdin.net/2012/07/indy-tiduri-pathencode-urlencode-and-paramsencode-and-more/)
- **HTTPApp.HttpEncode(url)** - Deprecated in Delphi 10.3
- **TNetEncoding.URL.Encode(s)** - [buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10133852/12597)

And then Windows itself has a selection of functions:

- [**InternetCanonicalizeUrl**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetcanonicalizeurla?redirectedfrom=MSDN) - only parses up to the `#` or `?`
- [**CoInternetParseUrl**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775089(v=vs.85)) - use with `PARSE_CANONICALIZE` and `URL_ESCAPE_UNSAFE`
- [**UrlCanonicalize**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-urlcanonicalizea)

If your FireMoney app is not running on Windows, then you might have to simply cave and roll your own.

Just be aware that [a lot of implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776302/standard-url-encode-function) will say that the only valid characters in URLs are:

```
`A`..`Z`, `a`..`z`, `0`..`9`, `-`, `_`, `~`, `.`
```

and escape anything else. When in reality the following is a valid and allowed URL:

```
http://example.com/:@-.!$&'(),=;:@-._~!$&'()*,=:@-.!$&'(),==?/?:@-._~!$'()*,;=/?:@-._~!$'()*,;==#/?:@-._~!$&'()*,;=
\__/   \_________/\________________________________________/\__________________________________/\_________________/
 |         |                         |                                        |                          |
Scheme   Host                       Path                                    Query                    Fragment
```

And each of your different *parts* have different rules about what is allowed.

| Part | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Scheme | `http` |
| Username |  |
| Password |  |
| Host | `example.com` |
| Port | `80` |
| Path | `/:@-.!$&'(),=;:@-._~!$&'()*,=:@-.!$&'(),==` |
| Query | `?/?:@-._~!$'()*,;=/?:@-._~!$'()*,;==` |
| Fragment | `#/?:@-._~!$&'()*,;=` |

What's more is that depending on your use case, maybe you **want** to urlencode the entire string:

- Before: `http://stackoverflow.com/`
- After:  `http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F`

When maybe in reality you only wanted it to escape "bad" urls:

- Before: `https://stackoverflow.com/terms of service`
- After: `https://stackoverflow.com/terms%20of%20service`

tl;dr: Try to use Windows.

Comment: None of the three Delphi ones you mention or the three Windows ones are available in TMS WEB Core.

Comment: Then the answer might really be limited to *"i'm afraid you might have to roll your own"*.  I mean i hate to leave it at that.